# GDB debug info parser/description

Tags: parsing, gdb, debug-symbols

During the work I faced with the following problem:

I need to parse GDB debug info.

Separate debug info file is a binary, so I can not read it without knowing a format.

So, here is the question:

Is there any ready parser for GDB info, or at least document describing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any ready parser for GDB info

There is no such thing. There are various debug info formats (`DWARF`, `STABS`, etc.) and multiple consumers of these debug formats (GDB is one such consumer).

If you are on Linux, the default debug format is `DWARF`, documented [here](http://dwarfstd.org/).

> I need to parse ... debug info

Depending on your actual needs, `readelf -w` or already mentioned `libdwarf` may be appropriate. Or you could write your own parser from scratch, though it's unlikely to be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at libdwarf. See http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdwarf/ or http://wiki.dwarfstd.org/index.php?title=Libdwarf_And_Dwarfdump